# Why website is broken when i reload the page?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, fuse

I used fuse template to build an angular project. I made it but when i reload the page website are broken. This is the mistake output:

**Server Error 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

Someone told that it is about app.module.ts but i do not know how to fix it. Could anyone help me to solve this problem?
Here is my app.module code=>

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ExtraOptions, PreloadAllModules, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MarkdownModule } from 'ngx-markdown';
import { FuseModule } from '@fuse';
import { FuseConfigModule } from '@fuse/services/config';
import { FuseMockApiModule } from '@fuse/lib/mock-api';
import { CoreModule } from 'app/core/core.module';
import { appConfig } from 'app/core/config/app.config';
import { mockApiServices } from 'app/mock-api';
import { LayoutModule } from 'app/layout/layout.module';
import { AppComponent } from 'app/app.component';
import { appRoutes } from 'app/app.routing';

const routerConfig: ExtraOptions = {
    preloadingStrategy       : PreloadAllModules,
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'
};

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports     : [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, routerConfig),

        // Fuse, FuseConfig & FuseMockAPI
        FuseModule,
        FuseConfigModule.forRoot(appConfig),
        FuseMockApiModule.forRoot(mockApiServices),

        // Core module of your application
        CoreModule,

        // Layout module of your application
        LayoutModule,

        // 3rd party modules that require global configuration via forRoot
        MarkdownModule.forRoot({})
    ],
    bootstrap   : [
        AppComponent,
    ],
})
export class AppModule
{
}
```

Comment: Is it happening on localhost?

Comment: No, it is not, it only happens after i published. Therefore, i cannot reload the page. it is going to down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update this line

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, routerConfig),
```

to

RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })

or

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [...],
    providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```